# Get the next href in a list in another file with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, list, href, attr

I've searched and searched, and it seems I'm stuck on this problem. 
Somehow I thought this wouldn't be too hard, and it probably isn't for anyone with a little more knowledge about jQuery.

I have an .html file, lets call it "originalfile.html", with a couple of lists, something like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <ul id="firstlist">
       <li class="link1"><a href="/path/link1.html" target="_blank"></a></li>
       <li class="link2"><a href="/path/link2.html" target="_blank"></a></li>
       <li class="link3"><a href="/path/link3.html" target="_blank"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="secondlist">
       <li class="link4"><a href="/path/link4.html" target="_blank"></a></li>
       <li class="link5"><a href="/path/link5.html" target="_blank"></a></li>
       <li class="link6"><a href="/path/link6.html" target="_blank"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The links open in a new window, and in the "link(x).html" files I would like "previous" and "next" buttons to keep going up/down the lists in the now closed original file, prefferably with some way to return to :first href when hitting ==0 in all the lists in the div #content, or in other words a loop.

The "next" and "prev" buttons should open the next/prev link in the list from the original file in the _self window, where the next file will have the same buttons, and so on.

I don't know if I'm going about this the right way at all, but I have gotten this far:

I get the current filename by using

```
var filename = location.pathname;
```

I then get the original list by using

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/path/originalfile.html',
   success: function(response) {
   $("#linkdiv").html(jQuery(response).find('#content').html());
   });
```

I'm using a new div "#linkdiv", then search for the current filename in that div

```
$("#linkdiv a[href=(filename)]");
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work, and how to find the next() and prev() href etc.
I believe I might be missing a .live somewhere?

Now the question is, is there somehow a way to do something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
   url: '/path/originalfile.html',
   success: function(response) {

   $("#next").html(jQuery(response).
   find('href with same value as current filename').
   next("href");

   $("#prev").html(jQuery(response).
   find('href with same value as current filename').
   prev("href");
   });
```

Now I know this code does not work, but would there be a way to find the href by using the current filename, then getting the previous and next href and attaching them to buttons with the id of #next and #prev ???

Comment: So you want a piece of code that can find a specific string in that markup and then tell you the previous and next elements ? P.S. You are going about this way wrong. For one you shouldn't be using requests from the pop-up to load the main page again...

Comment: As noted, I'm not really sure that I'm going about it the right way myself, but how then to get the values from a list in another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery doesn't seem to be the right tool for the job. If you really have 6 separate pages then they would each have their own set of navigation buttons. If you are doing some sort of template, or generated code then state that.

Also not sure why you would want to open into a new window?

> **HTML Page 1**

```
<ul id="firstlist">

   <li class="link2"><a href="/path/link2.html" target="_blank">Next</a></li>
   <li class="link3"><a href="/path/link3.html" target="_blank">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

> **HTML Page 2**

```
<ul id="firstlist">
   <li class="link1"><a href="/path/link1.html" target="_blank">Previous</a></li>

   <li class="link3"><a href="/path/link3.html" target="_blank">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

> **HTML Page 3**

```
<ul id="firstlist">
   <li class="link1"><a href="/path/link1.html" target="_blank">1</a></li>
   <li class="link2"><a href="/path/link2.html" target="_blank">Previous</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: There are of course a lot more than 6 pages, and the links are not so generic, otherwise I could just use the obvious html links to the next and previous pages in each page. But I'm considering doing it this way, as the pages are static, and not generated, it would just be easier to add pages in the list later if the links where updated based on the original list itself. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: if you have more than a couple of pages are you using any web framework? if not you should really consider it.

Comment: No, dont really know anything about that stuff? Started learning webdesign as a hobby two months ago :-) Are we talking php or asp or something similar?

Comment: WordPress is a great place to start if you plan on having more than two pages and plan on changing them at times. All that stuff is built in and you can focus on editing the content as opposed to wiring all the framework, that problem has long ago been solved.

Comment: Thank you for your help Bobby, but I already have my page laid out, this is for something I'm working on that will open quite a lot of technical documents in a custom flex application that is using swfadress, and so I would like the adressbar to update, so no modal, and would rather not open in _self, as the menu for all the links is controlled with UI sliders and selectors, and since the adressbar is updated with swfadress the back button does not function as espected by visitors, so I'm opening in _blank instead, but will need to find some way to get the prev and next from the original list!

Comment: if you mainly want to update the address bar might want to look into using hash codes. here.com#pageone, here.com#pagetwo, here.com#pagethree

Comment: Already got that covered by using swfadress, so it's not my goal, it's the reason for opening in blank window. What I really need is a way to get the next and previous href in a list loaded with ajax based solely on the current filenames location in that list?

Comment: Gave up, and did exactly as in your example in 500+ files. Lets hope I never have to change those list. Thank you for your help!